# Is it possible to install a Swedish font?

Tags: fonts

I want to install a Swedish font on Ubuntu, but I don't know its package name. What is its name?

Comment: What's a Swedish font? I thought Swedish uses the Latin alphabet. Do you mean Swedish translations?

Answer (score 4):

The package you are looking for is `language-pack-sv`

Install via the terminal with:

`sudo apt-get install language-pack-sv`

or through the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-sv

Comment: This should help: `sudo apt-cache search language-pack | grep Swedish`

Comment: sorry. Returns nothing.

Comment: Then most likely your repositories are disabled.